# GHDL 0.29 for Windows hangs if the number of statements in a process is even

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I'm using GHDL 0.29 for Windows.

The following program prints "Hello world!"

```
 use std.textio.all;

 entity hello_world is
 end hello_world;

 architecture behaviour of hello_world is
 begin
    process
       variable l : line;
    begin
       write (l, String'("Hello world!"));
       writeline (output, l);
       wait;
    end process;
 end behaviour;
```

The following program hangs and doesn't print anything.

```
 use std.textio.all;

 entity hello_world is
 end hello_world;

 architecture behaviour of hello_world is
 begin
    process
       variable l : line;
    begin
       assert false report "Foo" severity note;
       write (l, String'("Hello world!"));
       writeline (output, l);
       wait;
    end process;
 end behaviour;
```

The following program outputs the two assertions and then the "Hello world!" message.

```
 use std.textio.all;

 entity hello_world is
 end hello_world;

 architecture behaviour of hello_world is
 begin
    process
       variable l : line;
    begin
       assert false report "Foo" severity note;
       assert false report "bar" severity note;
       write (l, String'("Hello world!"));
       writeline (output, l);
       wait;
    end process;
 end behaviour;
```

I tried increasing the number of assertions and I discovered that when I have an odd number of assertions, the simulation hangs. It doesn't even matter where they are located. The following hangs:

```
   assert false report "Foo" severity note;
   assert false report "bar" severity note;
   assert false report "zoz" severity note;
   assert false report "lol" severity note;
   assert false report "mok" severity note;
   assert false report "antidisestablishmentarianism" severity note;
   write (l, String'("Hello world!"));
   writeline (output, l);
   wait;
   assert false report "asd" severity note;
```

The following prints everything up to the "antidisestablishmentarianism" assert:

```
   assert false report "Foo" severity note;
   assert false report "bar" severity note;
   assert false report "zoz" severity note;
   assert false report "lol" severity note;
   assert false report "mok" severity note;
   assert false report "antidisestablishmentarianism" severity note;
   write (l, String'("Hello world!"));
   writeline (output, l);
   wait;
   assert false report "asd" severity note;
   assert false report "gneeek" severity note;
```

**Edit**

The problem is more general, and seems to be related with the number of statements within a process being odd or even. The following prints "Hello world!Hello moon!" repeatedly:

```
 --  Hello world program.
 use std.textio.all; --  Imports the standard textio package.

 --  Defines a design entity, without any ports.
 entity hello_world is
 end hello_world;

 architecture behaviour of hello_world is
 begin
    process
       variable l : line;
    begin
       write (l, String'("Hello world!"));
       write (l, String'("Hello moon!"));
       writeline (output, l);
    end process;
 end behaviour;
```

While the following doesn't print anything and hangs:

```
 --  Hello world program.
 use std.textio.all; --  Imports the standard textio package.

 --  Defines a design entity, without any ports.
 entity hello_world is
 end hello_world;

 architecture behaviour of hello_world is
 begin
    process
       variable l : line;
    begin
       write (l, String'("Hello world!"));
       writeline (output, l);
    end process;
 end behaviour;
```

**Edit (this may save you some time)**

The weird behavior described above doesn't occur under Linux. Clearly, one of the two versions of GHDL is seriously flawed, and I strongly suspect that it is the Windows one. I'll file a bug report. I'm still interested in why the behavior is different.

**Edit (I also tried with version 0.25)**

With version 0.25 for Windows I get this error:

```
C:\Users\AjejeBrazorf\Documents\Programming\GHDL\Example>ghdl -a 1.vhdl
1.vhdl:1:10: file textio.v93 has changed and must be reanalysed
```

The ghdl.exe is the one packaged with the GTKWave bundle (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629872/415727).

Comment: There's a newer [installer] (http://ghdl.free.fr/download.html) for ghdl on windows for ghdl-0.29.1 you could try (unless you have it already).  I tried your test cases under a recent mcode version on OS X (uses the direct code to memory elaboration like the Windows version).  Your test cases passed.  See [Ghdl-discuss vhdl - GHDL 0.29 for Windows hangs if the number of statements in a process is even - Stack Overflow] (http://www.mail-archive.com/ghdl-discuss@gna.org/msg01721.html).  ghdl-0.29 is based on svn revision r143.  There are various changes through r150 plus some patches people use.

Comment: Interesting, the installer I had was called ghdl-win-installer-latest.exe. It looks like they released a new version in the meantime, or maybe I found that file somewhere else. I'll give it a try, thank you!

Comment: It runs fine on a freshly installed 0.29.1 for Windows, thank you. Interestingly enough, I installed GHDL on the 10th of May; now I'm wondering: where did I get the installer from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen [similar problems](https://mail.gna.org/public/ghdl-discuss/2011-08/msg00007.html) with the Windows GHDL 0.29.x builds.

Your example runs OK using either GHDL 0.25 or a [patched 0.29.1.](https://mail.gna.org/public/ghdl-discuss/2012-11/msg00004.html)

[GHDL 0.25 Windows build](http://ghdl.free.fr/ghdl-installer-0.25.exe)

**EDIT: note, the following bundled installer seems to have VHDL library timestamp issues**

[Handy bundle of GHDL 0.25 + GTK Wave](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpgalibre/files/GHDL/0.25_Windows), from [here](https://mail.gna.org/public/ghdl-discuss/2011-09/msg00001.html)

Comment: The bundle is a very nice resource, good to know. Thank you. However, with 0.25 I get a compile error on some imported file (see last edit). The code I tried to compile is the same as the first source in the question.

Comment: It actually works fine on a 0.29.1 downloaded from http://ghdl.free.fr/ghdl-installer-0.29.1.exe I may have missed that release for just a few hours when I downloaded GHDL on the 10th of May. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

( sorry for the separate answer rather than a comment, I don't have a Stack Overflow account and that's the only option I've found to post as a guest )

> With version 0.25 for Windows I get this error:
>
> C:\Users\AjejeBrazorf\Documents\Programming\GHDL\Example>ghdl -a
>   1.vhdl
>   1.vhdl:1:10: file textio.v93 has changed and must be reanalysed

**EDIT : updated with library re-analyze info**

I could run your "hang" examples using the GHDL 0.25 link from the ghdl website with no such library errors.

So I tried installing the GHDL+GTK bundle on another XP box, and I see the same library errors as you.

The problem is that the GHDL library timestamps are out of sync with the library std-obj93.cf file, probably a timestamp issue with the installer creation.

Here's how to manually re-analyze a GHDL library, using the VHDL-93 textio as an example:

```
C:\>cd "\Program Files\FPGALibre\GHDL_GTKWave\lib\v93\std"

C:\Program Files\FPGALibre\GHDL_GTKWave\lib\v93\std>ghdl -a --std=93 --bootstrap --work=std textio.v93

C:\Program Files\FPGALibre\GHDL_GTKWave\lib\v93\std>ghdl -a --std=93 --bootstrap --work=std textio_body.v93
```

After performing those steps, I can run your 'hang' example with the GHDL_0.25+GTK bundle:

```
>ghdl -a hello_world.vhd

>ghdl -r hello_world
hello_world.vhd:11:7:@0ms:(assertion note): Foo
Hello world!
```

> It runs fine on a freshly installed 0.29.1 for Windows, thank you.
>   Interestingly enough, I installed GHDL on the 10th of May; now I'm
>   wondering: where did I get the installer from?

The "new" GHDL download wiki page on ghdl.free.fr has an outdated link to that '-latest' Windows installer that you mentioned.

David and I both pointed directly to the hidden "old" GHDL download page.

see also:
https://mail.gna.org/public/ghdl-discuss/2011-01/msg00007.html

Note that the 0.25 link I provided is not visible on either GHDL download page.

> It actually works fine on a 0.29.1

Note that if you are doing anything with resolved signals, Windows GHDL 0.29.1 also tends to crash.

For Windows, I would recommend running either 0.25 or a patched 0.29.1 as described in the earlier links.